# Fortran with Apple silicon m1

Tags: fortran

I have intalled M1 gfortran, "gfortran-ARM-11.0-BigSur.tar.xz"
And I try compile as "sudo gfortran -ffree-form "Melodia2021.f""
but it outputs "ld: library not found for -lm".

Comment: Aren't `.f` files fixed form and not free form?

Comment: The default interpretation of `.f` is fixed-form.  The explicit use of the `-ffree-form` option overrides this interpretation.

Comment: I use -ffree-form option because of long lines in source code.

Comment: [-ffree-form](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html#Fortran-Dialect-Options) sets the source to free form, but this still has a maximum line length. You can use [-ffree-line-length-none](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html#Fortran-Dialect-Options) to remove the maximum line length from free form source.

Comment: But still anyway "ld: library not found for -ld", gfortran can not compile.